# Limit response data to just city and state using jQuery UI Autocomplete and Geobytes API

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I am using jQuery UI Autocomplete and jQuery $.ajax to get cities and states from Geobytes web service.  My goal is to have an autocomplete text input for all the cities and states within the U.S.  Now, I was able to limit the data call to just the cities and states within the U.S., but when the autocomplete results shows up, the "United States" part also shows up.  For example, if I type in "cin", the cities, states and the "United States" part shows up.  How can I have the results to just show the cities and states without the "United States" part?

Here is my JS code:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          data: {
            filter: "US",
            q: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
            response( data );
          }
        });
      },
      minLength: 3

    });
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am the creator of Goebytes'AutoCompleteCity API, and I have just added a template parameter that allows you to format the returned list - to exclude the country or state, or even include some other city attribute, but in any case to answer your question - just add template: ", " to the parameters that you are passing in - like this

```
data: {
        filter: "US",
        template: "<geobytes city>, <geobytes code>",
        q: request.term
      },
```

There is a bit more of an explaination on the API's main page here: http://www.geobytes.com/free-ajax-cities-jsonp-api/

The issue then may be if you are using the user's selection to fetch the details of the city that they select via the GetCityDetails API - in which case you will need to remember to append the truncated part back on.